# What is the meaning of "no less" here? Is it positive or negative?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

In other words, in the definition we have given of it, is it really possible to add to the boundary between the science of personality and the biological sciences a **no less** firmly established boundary, on the other side of the terrain thus sketched out, between the science of personality and the social sciences?

Answer (score 3):

... a no less firmly established boundary, - a boundary which is at least as firmly established. It is similar to the Maths "not less than" which is mathematically the same as "greater than or equal to".